# Mysql Insert into with select from myisam to innodb

Tags: mysql, insert, innodb, calculated-columns, myisam

I have a table, which is accessed by multiple worker applications, which grab a batch of records, calculate some stuff on them and update the calculated result back into this table. This table is currently MyISAM based, but since we had some changes to our calculating algorithm and it resulted in a huge speed up, we have seen loads of locks on the table, which is expected as it's a MyISAM table. (The table has around **650-700 000** records in it).

Once all the records are processed, a report is generated based on it and the table is truncated. Once the table is truncated, a processes reinitalizeses it and the cycle starts again.

I was thinking about switching over the MyISAM table to InnoDB to prevent locks, but the processes, which initalizes the table with a `INSERT INTO .. SELECT .. FROM` statement (which used to take 3-4 mintues), was running for 35-40 minutes when i decided to stop it. Why is this? Is there a way to speed it up?

Comment: What's the output from a DESC on the select?

Comment: There is no WHERE clause in the SELECT so it is pretty simple (there is a reason this is done this way, and as i wrote, when both tables where MyISAM, the insert took 3-4 minutes. 

| id | select_type | table                   | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table_name | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 681233 |       |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+------+---------------

Comment: Maybe something useful here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671122/mysql-converting-from-myisam-to-innodb-makes-queries-faster?rq=1

Comment: you can try others methods like export/import but your db is big, so you need to be patient anyway

Comment: I don't think it is a question of patiance if your query becomes at least 10 times slower... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyISAM stores records in the order they're inserted. On the other hand, InnoDB's primary key is a clustered index, so records are physically stored in the same order as the primary key. Therefore, ensure you're inserting in primary key order. You can add an ORDER BY clause to the INSERT INTO ... SELECT.

Also, to avoid split pages and rebuilding of your secondary indexes, add your secondary indexes after you've inserted the initial rows. So, remove the indexes, then re-add them after.

Also, to avoid the row locking (and auto-increment locking) overhead, explicitly lock the tables with LOCK TABLES.

Finally, increase [innodb_buffer_pool_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size), otherwise your indexes will build very slowly. The default is only 8MB.

Comment: I'm doing a lock, sorry, i forgot that, so that's alreay in place.

Comment: so you mean INSERT INTO .. SELECT .. FROM order by pk; ? That's weird, i'll give it a try.

Comment: @ZsoltJános, I added to my answer.

Comment: I made a test on  my sytem with order by (with 680 000 records) and there was no difference, order by was slightly slower - though it took only 3 minutes 30 seconds...

Comment: innodb_buffer_pool_size will be the solution.